# Cmake not compiling for basic PCL exmaple

Tags: cmake, pcl

I am trying to build https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/writing_pcd.html. using the following cmake on my university supercomputer:

```
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23 FATAL_ERROR)
project(project)
set(Boost_NO_WARN_NEW_VERSIONS 1)
set(VTK_DIR  /software/spackages/linux-rocky8-x86_64/gcc-9.5.0/vtk-9.0.3-hfji6zde3waya5ig7cvvsmdylzvmdrty/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0)
find_package(PCL 1.11 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io search impl)
set(PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS /software/spackages/linux-rocky8-x86_64/gcc-9.5.0/pcl-1.11.1-5ymdvadjcubkab43zen2svmiwnh5hmga/include/pcl-1.11 /software/spackages/linux-rocky8-x86_64/gcc-9.5.0/eigen-3.4.0-odvljtj76a2twpnkiztib7qiod346tjp)
cmake_print_variables(PCL_LIBRARIES)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(pcd_write_test pcl_view.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcd_write_test ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/pcl_view.cpp:5: warning: "_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI" redefined
 #define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:38,
                 from /home/rgadde/courses/CPSC4780/project/pcl_view.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h:2204: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 1
 
[100%] Linking CXX executable pcd_write_test
/software/spackages/linux-rocky8-x86_64/gcc-9.5.0/pcl-1.11.1-5ymdvadjcubkab43zen2svmiwnh5hmga/lib/libpcl_io.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
/software/spackages/linux-rocky8-x86_64/gcc-9.5.0/pcl-1.11.1-5ymdvadjcubkab43zen2svmiwnh5hmga/lib/libpcl_io.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/build.make:137: pcd_write_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

How can this error be resolved?

I tried the following:

1. Added  `# define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0`
2. Compiled using `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ ..`

Comment: From [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html): "_Call the cmake_minimum_required() command at the beginning of the top-level CMakeLists.txt file even before calling the project() command. It is important to establish version and policy settings before invoking other commands whose behavior they may affect._"

Comment: I'm not very familiar with gcc distribution/packaging/installation things, but I noticed you hard-code paths saying `gcc-9.5.0`, and your include directory is `/usr/include/c++/8/iostream`. Is that normal?

Comment: Its the installed path for the package on the supercomputer. We are not allowed to build our own packages, have to use installed ones.